# distributing r distinct objects into n-distinct boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've just started with the basic principles of counting which includes the Multiplication Principle.

suppose a procedure designated by $1$ can be performed in $n1$ ways. Let us assume that a second procedure , designated by $2$ can be performed in $n2$ ways. Suppose also that each way of doing $1$ may be followed by any way of doing $2$.Then the procedure consisting of $1$ followed by $2$ may be performed in $n1\times n2$.
[image]

There's a distribution problem which says that:

No. of ways of distributing $r$ distinct objects into $n$ distinct boxes,if each box can have any number of objects is $n^r$

If I have to relate this problem with above diagram what should be my $n_1$,$n_2$$\ldots$ $n_r$. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a diagram like that you would use $n_1=n, n_2=n, \ldots, n_k=n, \ldots, n_r= n$

There would be $r$ distinct steps each with $n$ possible ways.  That corresponds to selecting one of $n$ boxes to put a ball into, for $r$ balls.

The diagram would consist of $r$ lines, the starting point branching to $n$ points on the first line, each one with $n$ branches to the the next line, and each of those $n^2$ points starting $n$ branches to the third line, and each of those $n^3$ points branching $n$ times ... until each of the $n^{r-1}$ points on the penultimate line start $n$ branches to the last line, for a total of $n^r$ points on line $r$.

$$\underbrace{n_1\times n_2 \times \cdots \times n_r}_{\text{a term for each of $r$ balls}} = \underbrace{\quad n\times n\times \cdots \times n\quad}_{\text{each term is the count of boxes, $n$}} = n^r$$

Comment: thanks for the answer. But now what I can't understand is that where did we ensure that any no. of balls can be placed in a box.as you said 'to put a ball into' but we can put any no. of balls not just one .please explain I'm confused.

Comment: Is it so that each ball has n possibility. then I understood it should be $n^r$.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract, There's no need to ensure anything.  "The boxes can contain any number of balls" simply means that where you place any one ball does not effect where you can place the others.  So you can put each individual ball into any of the $n$ boxes.

Comment: So if you have, say, 3 balls and 4 boxes, and you put the first ball into any box, the second ball into any box, and the third ball into any box.  Then when you are done each box will contain any number of the balls: from none, one, two, to all three., depending on how you placed them.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the doubt.

Comment: Could somebody tell me if this is same as permutation with repetition? I'm confused whether distribution of distinct to distinct is the same as permutations with repetitions or not. Atleast the formulae seem to be the same $n^r$

Comment: Yes. That is what it is, @salvinod'sa

Comment: Specifically: the permutation count for $r$ selections from $n$ options with repetition allowed.